# Android Localizer 1.5

Tags: android, localization

I'm trying to use this app http://www.artfulbits.com/products/free/ailocalizer.aspx#Introduction_1 but without opening the actual project folder. So I copied the resources to another folder, but the app can't recognize the other folder as a project folder.

The question is - why? What else I need to do for this app to recognize and work in the other folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must also copy AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: Thanks. I managed to figure it out but I hope this will be useful for other people. The AndroidMAnifest.xml could also be blank - it does not matter as long as there is a file with this name in the parent folder, simulating an android project folder structure.